# python ipow : how to use the third argument?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

In the official python documentation in the Data model section, the [`__ipow__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ipow__) is defined as:

```
object.__ipow__(self, other[, modulo])
```

Then, the documentation explains that *These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments* (`**=` for `__ipow__`)

But what is the syntax of `**=` that allows to use the `modulo` argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument is there just for symmetry with `__pow__`.

The argument was included in the original ['add in-place operator equivalents' commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/52fd496d3532/Objects/abstract.c) but there is no support to use it from Python code, other than calling the `__ipow__` method *directly*.

For example, the `INPLACE_POWER` opcode handling [passes in `None`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f13f1620d70/Python/ceval.c#l1483) as the third argument:

```c
case INPLACE_POWER:
    w = POP();
    v = TOP();
    x = PyNumber_InPlacePower(v, w, Py_None);
    Py_DECREF(v);
    Py_DECREF(w);
    SET_TOP(x);
    if (x != NULL) continue;
    break;
```

Most likely it is there to make implementing `__ipow__` as an alias for `__pow__` trivial even from C code.

Comment: This is a strange choice of design. It would be simpler to just remove the third argument from the doc, but anyway, thanks for your clear answer !